# Under guest virtual machine, Debian hangs when loading initial ramdisk

Tags: debian, windows, virtualbox, ramdisk

I am new to *Linux*, and recently installed **Debian 8** to a guest virtual machine running under **Virtual Box** on a **Windows 8** laptop (Asus x552cl).

When I try boot up the Debian system, the virtual machine completely freezes while loading the ramdisk -- I can't even call the console.  I thought it was because of my **Nvidia** video card. I disabled it with Window's device manager, tried to reboot Linux, but it didn't help.

Also, when I was installing Debian it took nearly *30 hours* to finish.

Before this I had tried to get **Ubuntu** as second (virtual machine) OS, but just like with Debian, I ran in the same black screen of death.  What may might be wrong, and how should I fix it?

Comment: On the Asus x552cl, what is the host OS that Virtual Box is running under?

Comment: Windows 8.1 is the one

Comment: Now, were you 1) trying to install Debian to a disk image file which would always run under virtual box, or 2) using VBox to run an installer to put Debian on a non-virtual partition of a physical hard drive, (i.e. a dual boot system).

Comment: 1st case only virtual drive

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that it shouldnt take 30hrs to install and it might be a corrupt ISO. Have you tried downloading a new ISO and reinstall?

If not, here are 3 conversations on the black screen issue that may help-

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/debian-wheezy-black-screen-on-launch-after-successful-install-4175475144/

and

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842

and

https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver

Also, you may want to try vmware player. Its free.

Comment: Yes I tried few iso's from the official site, it was the same. I have used DVD, CD as well as netinstall disc. Thanks for the link I'm gonna check it out

Comment: @AlexBuddy Did you get the issue solved? If so how? I'm here from the first result of google